# Is it possible to change default hive partition value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue metastore for Hive.

When we have records that land in AWS S3 that have null data for the partition columns, Hive by default gives them a partition value of:

> **_HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION_**

This is causing issues, as our partition column is an integer but this is a string value.

Is there a setting somewhere we can leverage to give it an integer default value?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting `hive.exec.default.partition.name` which you can try and change at your own risk. From Hive [Config Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties):

> **hive.exec.default.partition.name**
>   Default Value: `_HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION_`
>  
>   Added In: Hive 0.6.0 
>   The default partition name in case the dynamic partition column value is null/empty string
>   or any other values that cannot be escaped. This value must not
>   contain any special character used in HDFS URI (e.g., ':', '%', '/'
>   etc). The user has to be aware that the dynamic partition value should
>   not contain this value to avoid confusions.

If you already have a partition for NULLs, that can be renamed (moved) to a new name to preserve the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the column to string, drop the **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**, and then change the column back to Int?
Sorry, I didnt work on AWS Glue metastore.

Through Hive:

```
alter table <tablename> set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='True');
alter table <tablename> change id int string;
alter table <tablename> set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='False');
alter table <tabename> drop partition(id='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__');

alter table <tablename> set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='True');
alter table <tablename> change id string int;
alter table <tablename> set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='False');
```

Comment: Yes actually we considered this approach, but we have real time data being loaded so we didn't want to complicate things by change column type and dropping when real data can be coming in and then getting errors in our process.

Comment: realtime data flow shouldn't impact as hive doesn't do strict datatype check. Alternatively, you can just go to hdfs and remove the folder manually. This way, Hive shows data as empty.